# When I use cheerio to scrape a img src, I get back a gigantic string instead of just the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

```
const img = $('div.class a).attr('src')
```

I'm sure there is just something I am missing about the src attribute and images in general, but how do I get back just the short link I see displayed after the src attribute and not the entire image data?

pulling from

```
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f%2B2GYfneL._SX323_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg" onload="if(this.width/this.height > 0.84){this.className += ' a-stretch-horizontal'}else{this.className += ' a-stretch-vertical'};this.onload='';" class="a-dynamic-image image-stretch-vertical frontImage a-stretch-vertical" id="imgBlkFront" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f%2B2GYfneL._SX323_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg&quot;:[325,499],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f%2B2GYfneL._SY344_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg&quot;:[226,346]}" style="max-width: 226px; max-height: 346px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 174.181px; height: 266.667px;">
```

returns

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

I expected

```
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f%2B2GYfneL._SX323_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg"
```

Comment: What's the source HTML?

Comment: Looks like at some point before you run your code the image's `src` is changed to a data URI.

Comment: Based on the JavaScript you've posted, it doesn't look like that code would select the `img` mark up you've posted.

I've created a minimal reproduction of this scenario in [repl.it](https://repl.it/@piboistudios/RareFrightenedHack) and I'm getting the expected output.

Comment: Also, the JS posted is invalid syntax. I imagine it's not the actual code being run to give you the results you've received.

Comment: is there a way to just get the literal text behind the src attribute? I know it's pulling the right img and data because it works if you paste it in somewhere. I could just use this string for my purposes but it doesn't look very nice to me. rather have the link.

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid answer can really be deduced based on the information you've provided. Something that's not detailed within your question is happening, as the REPL indicates that the link is not being changed to a Base64 string internally by `cheerio`

Comment: @user1538301 it pulls the image src because I'm getting back the image I want, I just want it in a different format. Is there something I can do to just get the literal text behind the src attribute and not the long image string?

Comment: @mowgmowg That's kind of what I'm saying. You may well know that it's selecting the right thing because you have the code and markup fully at your disposal. Based on the information provided, we cannot see why this is happening. My attempt at reproducing your issue yields the correct results.

Comment: I mean, we don't even have the actual JS you're running to get these results, the JS in your question doesn't have valid syntax, and therefore could not be the same code you are running.

Comment: What's not valid about the syntax?

Comment: `const img = $('div.class a).attr('src') ` Unclosed single quote.

Comment: that's pretty obviously a typo here, if I'm receiving the data back you should be able to assume that's not the case in my code.

Comment: does this help?   const img = $("div#img-canvas img")
      .attr("src")
      .trim();

Comment: We need the code and the markup you are using to be able to give you an accurate answer. Of course I assumed that is not the case in your code, that is why I stated "we don't even have the actual JS you're running to get these results".

And again, based on the markup you've provided, the JS you've provided doesn't select the image you're trying to select. The image you're trying to select based on the markup you've provided has an ID of `#imgBlkFront` and classes `.a-dynamic-image.image-stretch-vertical.frontImage.a-stretch-vertical`

Comment: @user1538301 thank you for your attention to this. I appreciate you taking the time to help :) I've decided to just use the string since I can just display the image and won't really have to directly interact with the long string anyway. Just wanted it to be neater. Again thank you for your time!